# (VSC) Terminal Issues When Running Commands (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmd, terminal

I'm a beginner when it comes to coding so I have very little knowledge of what is going on with this. 
Please explain simply for me if possible.

c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'TripleX.cpp': No such file or directory

This is the type of error i'm getting when I try to find a directory with the default powershell being CMD.

Another problem I have is what my code opens when I try to run it. When I right click the file up in
open editors and click open in new terminal, when I do a cl command it actually works.
However, when I run it, the power shell switches to code, notepad, or visual studio 2019. I need help fixing this. (Btw none of the 3 listed applications actually run the code. They just open with the code inside).
I've tried switching what application VSC opens the code with.
I've tried moving the file around to see if cmd can reach the file.

Comment: The error indicates that the source folder does not contain the file `TripleX.cpp`

Comment: @drescherjm The file exists but how do I get VSC to look for it? (Sorry for the wrong product tag). And how do I get it to stop opening Notepad or other applications?

Comment: The path is set in your json settings. [[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc)